# Remove white spaces from both ends of a string inside a form - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, trim

I have a simple form that receives the first name and last name, and I need to remove the whitespaces in the beginning and end of the string. I can do this with the `.trim()` method, but because is a form, it doesn't let me write a name that has two words, such as Ana Maria, because it doesn't let me press the space key at the end of a word. How can I remove white spaces from both sides of a string but still let me press space and write more than one word?

[image]

This is the component:

```
export default function ScheduleInput(
  { label, required, onChange, value, ...extraProps },
) {
  return (
    <div className="item_container">
      {label}:
      {required &&
        <span style={{ color: 'red' }}> *</span>
      }
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value.trim()}
        {...extraProps}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you should let the user type what he wants and use `trim` function into a `onBlur` event to validate the data when the user leave the field, if you use `trim` into the `onChange` handler, he won't be able to use the space character

Comment: Do you mean? `string.trimLeft().trimRight()`?

Comment: Either trim on blur or trim before submit of data, I usually trim and validate b4 submission.

Comment: @Ashish https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @coreyward Yeah sure, `trim` is good, just thought for a second, can using the left & right specifically get you faster times? But anyway, looks like, that right now isn't exactly the concern.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of trimming `onChange`, do that in an `onBlur` callback:

```
<input onBlur={this.props.formatInput} {...} />
```

Where that might look something like this:

```
formatInput = (event) => {
  const attribute = event.target.getAttribute('name')
  this.setState({ [attribute]: event.target.value.trim() })
}
```

Comment: how to identify attribute name from target?

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work when you hit the enter key to submit?

Comment: To trim when you hit enter add this to input (when using useState):`onKeyPress={(e) => {if (e.key === "Enter") {setValue(e.target.value.trim())}
}}`