# React / Javascript - Remove white spaces from both ends of a string and extra spaces between words, from a input field (search bar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

I have a search bar that fetches movies from an API with the name of the movie [ on every keystroke].
I want to trim the extra spaces from both before and after the name, and only have one space between words..

[It should send the clean string to the query to be fetched]

example:
[(what i'm typing)    ==> (what should be queried)]
`"    gran     torino    "`  ==> `"gran torino"`
`"  Pirates  of      the    Caribbean     "`   ==>   `"Pirates of the Caribbean"`

[search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKDqc.png)
[state value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VzOn.png)

code:

```
const fetchMovieList = async (query) => {
        if (query !== '') {
            setStatusFetch('loading');
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`[API]=${query}`);
                const movieListFromApi = await res.json();
                if (movieListFromApi.Response === 'True') {
                    setStatusFetch('resolved');
                    setStatusMovie('found');
                    setMovieList(movieListFromApi.Search);
                } else {
                    setMovieList([]);
                    setStatusMovie('notFound');
                }
                setStatusFetch('idle');
            } catch (error) {
                setStatusFetch('rejected');
            }
        } else {
            setMovieList([]);
            setStatusMovie('');
        }
    };
```

```
const myDebouncedFunction = useCallback(debounce((query) => fetchMovieList(query), 1000), []);
```

```
const handleSearch = ({ target: { value: inputValue } }) => {
    setSearchInputValue(inputValue);
    myDebouncedFunction(inputValue);
};
```

```
<SearchBar 
    type='text' 
    name='query' 
    placeholder='Search movies...' 
    value={searchInputValue} 
    onChange={handleSearch} 
    icon='fa fa-search' />
```

NON WORKING SOLUTIONS
- .trim() doesn't allow me to use spaces between words..
- onBlur won't help either because i wont unfocus from the search bar. ([Remove white spaces from both ends of a string inside a form - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284334/remove-white-spaces-from-both-ends-of-a-string-inside-a-form-react))
- several regex expressions that i tried wouldn't allow spaces between words to (like .trim()) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636022/3186426)

How can i do it?? Im i missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove extra spaces in string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974664/remove-extra-spaces-in-string-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to trim an input while you are typing. If you trim while you type, you will not be able to add spaces between text.

You can let the user type whatever they want on the input, and before you do that API call, you remove the spaces using the `removeExtraSpace` example above, and then when the request finish you can, if you want update the input value.

Check the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/trim-before-8efz5

Comment: How to do in React Native ?

Answer (score 7):

```js
const test = "  Pirates  of      the    Caribbean     ";

const removeExtraSpace = (s) => s.trim().split(/ +/).join(' ');

console.log(removeExtraSpace(test))
```

You may want to check if string is empty first

Answer (score 2):

With a simple and quick one liner.

```
"  Pirates  of      the    Caribbean     ".replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ').trim() 

// "Pirates of the Caribbean"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let data="  Pirates  of      the    Caribbean     "
    let data1=data.trim().split('  ').filter(word=>word!=='')
    console.log(data1)
   data=data1.join(' ')
    console.log("Data=",data)
```